# In Scheme, Is there a filter like function defined in the R5RS specification?

Tags: scheme, r5rs, mit-scheme

My baseline for this questions comes from MIT's *Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs*. In the book, a filter function is defined. I know that map is part of the spec, but I see nothing resembling filter.

EDIT:
Specifically I'm referring to the spec here: http://www.schemers.org/Documents/Standards/R5RS/HTML/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. [This SFRI](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-1/srfi-1.html) specifically requests that a filter function be added because it is not present in R5RS. There is however a filter function defined [in MIT-Scheme](http://www.gnu.org/software/mit-scheme/documentation/mit-scheme-ref/Filtering-Lists.html), and [in R6RS](http://www.r6rs.org/final/html/r6rs-lib/r6rs-lib-Z-H-4.html#node_idx_208), behaving exactly as one would expect.

Comment: That seems to be specific to MIT scheme only. I'm wondering whether  a *filter* like function is part of the R5RS specification. For e.g, Gambit scheme does not have filter.

Comment: In a newer version of the Scheme report, [R6RS](http://www.r6rs.org/final/html/r6rs-lib/r6rs-lib-Z-H-4.html#node_idx_208), we have `filter` amongst other higher order procedures.